# R-markdown keeps evaluating comments - is this intended behaviour?

Tags: r, r-markdown, comments

Here is my R-markdown file:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: Sombody

output: 
  ioslides_presentation

---

```{r setup, include = F}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  comment = ''
)

```

```{r test, echo = F}
x <- seq(1,10)
y <- sin(x)
plot(x,y)


```
<!--

```{r missing variable, echo = F}
z+3

```

-->
````

When I try to generate html output, I get:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'z' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
```

Why is markdown keep evaluating comments? I thought I can use `<!-- -->` to disable big chunks of code and debug.

Comment: I use the chunk option `eval=F` to "disable" code chunks.

Comment: See also : https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1363

Comment: @Waldi, ty, question answered.